# Change default text for multiple select input on ios

Tags: html, ios, css

I'd like to change the "n items" text displayed by iOS for multiple select inputs to something like "n shirt types".

I'm not sure if this is currently possible, but would like to know either way.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue? I am also suffering because of it :( Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't at the time, I'm not sure if iOS has updated since then, but I ended up building a custom select widget

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about displaying different things on a website if the user is on an iOS device versus a computer? You could always do a [media query](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to find out device size and then display different inputs by setting the display property to none.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to change the label of a dropdown menu for a form. This can easily be done by using the `<label>` tag just before your `<select>` tag. An example is as follows:

```
<form>
    <label>n Shirt types</label>
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```